# What is the geometric interpretation of this matrix?

Tags: linear-transformations, euclidean-geometry, tensors, bilinear-form

Let $x$ be some vector in two dimensions. To make my question clearer, let me start with an example where I know the solution: The matrix
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{x_1x_1+x_2x_2}\begin{pmatrix}x_2x_2&-x_1x_2\\-x_2x_1&x_1x_1\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
is interpreted as the projection onto the subspace spanned by $x$ (more precisely, the representation w.r.t. some basis). That being said, what is the interpretation of the following matrix:
\begin{equation}
T:=\begin{pmatrix}x_2x_2&-x_1x_2\\-x_2x_1&x_1x_1\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
For example, we may think of $T$ as the representation of a vector space endomorphism (as above) or a bilinear form w.r.t. a basis. The matrix $T$ appears in the discussion of tensors in Riley, Hobson and Bence (3rd).

Comment: Not sure what to say about it, but there is an obvious factorization:
$$T=\begin{pmatrix}x_2 & 0 \\ 0 & x_1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x_2 & 0 \\ 0 & x_1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Furthermore, $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1\\-1 & 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\-1 & 1\end{pmatrix}^T\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\-1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, hence $T=P^TP$ with $P=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\-x_2 & x_1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thank you for the comments. It is a good idea to decompose $T$, but I think that we need to find a decomposition in terms of tensors to obtain a geometric interpretation and $P$ is not a tensor, is it?

Comment: Yes, it is the tensor $\binom{x_1}{-x_2}(x_1,-x_2) \in (R^2) \otimes (R^2)^*$

Comment: @JeanMarie But $\binom{x_1}{-x_2}$ is not vector, because $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$ does not commute with an arbitrary rotation, does it?

Comment: I'm not a physicist, but it seems like this matrix would be the [inertia tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) for a single point with unit mass. This may yield some intuitive understanding what the matrix does - if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: "If that is what you are looking for" YES, thank you! Do you know the basis-independent definition of $\mathbf T$? I would like to have some definition such that I can **prove** that the matrix in my question is the representation w.r.t. a basis.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as it can be written under the following matrix form:

$$\binom{ \ \ x_1}{-x_2}(x_1 \ \ -x_2) $$

which, being the product of column vector and a row vector is interpretable as a tensorial expression from $$(\mathbb{R}^2) \otimes (\mathbb{R}^2)^*$$

**Edit 1:** Why row vectors can be identified with linear mappings $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \to ax+by \in \mathbb{R}$ ? Because one can write them :

$$\binom{x}{y} \ \to \ (a \ \ b)\binom{x}{y}$$

**Edit 2:** In fact, there is a second reason for assimilating the given matrix to a tensor product : it is the fact that it can be written

$$(x_1 \ \ -x_2) \oplus \binom{x_1}{-x_2}$$

where this time $\oplus$ denotes the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of 2 matrices.

Comment: I have seen your comment, but I am sorry, I don't understand it.

Comment: "I have seen your comment, but I am sorry, I don't understand it." By assumption $x=(x_1,x_2)$ are the components of a vector $\mathbf x$ w.r.t. a fixed orthonormal basis, meaning that $x'=Lx$ under a change of basis. But $(x_1,-x_2)=Ax$ (where $A$ is the matrix from my last comment) are not the components of a vector, since we do not have $Ax'=ALx=LAx$ in general.

Comment: Now I understand. As I work with respect to the canonical bases of both $R^2$ and $R^{2*}$, I hadn't seen the problem. But does this issue subsist if you do **simultaneously** the basis change in  $R^2$ and $R^{2*}$ ? Besides, see the little Edit I just added explaining (once again with respect to the canonical bases) my "point of view".

Comment: "But does this issue subsist if..." - No, as shown in the book $T$ can be interpreted as the representation of a tensor w.r.t. an orthonormal basis, i.e. the matrix transforms like a tensor (since $x$ is assumed to transform like a vector).  I am interested in the **tensor** $\mathbf T$, so if we can find true vectors $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf w$ such that $\mathbf T=\mathbf v\otimes\mathbf w$ (I am assuming an inner product on $V$, i.e. we can identify $V$ with $V^*$), then this would solve the problem, but I don't think that we can...

Comment: I must think about that. I will be back in some hours.

Comment: See the little edit Ijust added.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Let $\mathbf g$ be the inner product. As mentioned above it defines a vector space isomorphism $\mathbf g\in L(V,V^*)$. That being said:$$\mathbf T=\mathbf g(\mathbf x,\mathbf x)\mathbf g+\mathbf g(\mathbf x)\otimes\mathbf g(\mathbf x)\in V^*\otimes V^*$$This is the manifestly coordinate-independent definition of $\mathbf T$.

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't had this view...

Comment: Sorry, the plus should be a minus:$$\mathbf T=\mathbf g(\mathbf x,\mathbf x)\mathbf g-\mathbf g(\mathbf x)\otimes\mathbf g(\mathbf x)$$Btw, this is indeed the formula for the inertia tensor.